# Where is the Nautilus icon stored?

Tags: nautilus, icons

I am using Ubuntu 20.4.2, and I need to know where Nautilus (aka "Files") stores its blue filing cabinet icon.

Comment: The default Nautilus icon in Ubuntu 20.04.2 is a white Folder, not a blue filing cabinet. You need to tell us which icon theme you are using. You can also attach a screenshot of the icon you are referring to.

Comment: BTW you are also behind in updates. If it was full up to date it would be 20.04.3

Comment: Icons are usually stored in /usr/share/icons. You'll need to search the subfolders for whatever it's called.

Comment: Screenshot is better than words. Please add it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out as following.

- The icon is defined in the `.desktop` launcher of nautilus. Typically, the `.desktop` launcher will be under `/usr/local/share`, but you could find it with a command like `find / -name '*.desktop' -exec grep -H "Files" {} \; 2>/dev/null`, where "Files" is the name that is displayed in the application overvies.
- By default, the launcher for files is `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop`. Inspect its content to look at the line `Icon=`. Alternatively, display that line with the command `cat /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop | grep Icon`. The icon thus is specified as `org.gnome.Nautilus`.
- `org.gnome.Nautilus` refers to a graphics file in the standard locations of the system. The command `find / -name 'org.gnome.Nautilus.*' 2>/dev/null` shows you all files of which the name starts with `org.gnome.Nautilus`. Look for files under `icons` folders. On a standard Ubuntu system, you will find it under icons for the Humanity icon theme and under the Yaru icon theme. The icon belonging to the current icon theme will be used, if available. Otherwise, the fallback will be `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/org.gnome.Nautilus.svg`, which is actually the original icon.